# How to send and receive UDP Pakets on Lego Mindstorms EV3 using Simulink External Mode?

Tags: c, matlab, udp, simulink, lego-mindstorms

I am trying to create a simulink block using c-code for my EV3 to send the measured value from its sensors and/or receive datas from other hardware (raspberry pi) via UDP Pakets. However I can't find any concrete example in internet. I tried to write my own code following the example from https://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html. I expected it to work, since EV3 is a linux system. However, it is not working.

The c-code library of the udp_receiver (**updated**):

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// BUFLEN = max size
#define BUFLEN 512
#define NPACK 1


double * linux_udp_empfaenger(int32_t PORT)
{
  struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;

  int s, i, j, slen = sizeof(si_other) , recv_len;
  char buf[BUFLEN];
  //char buf_h[BUFLEN];
  unsigned short recv_port = (unsigned short) PORT;
  double * data;

  //create a UDP socket
  if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
  {
    return 0;
    exit(1);
  } else{

    // zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

   si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
   si_me.sin_port = htons(recv_port);
   si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

   //bind socket to port
   if( bind(s , (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
   {
     close(s);
     return 0;
     exit(1);
   } else{

    //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
    //memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);

    for (i=0; i<NPACK; i++) {
     if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)==-1)
      {
        close(s);
        return 0;
       } else {
        //Convert buf into usable host format
        //buf_h = ntohs(buf);

        // Convert data from string to double
        //data = atof(buf);

        int N_DATA = sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]);

        for (j = 0; j < N_DATA; j++){
        data[j] = (double)be64toh(((uint64_t *)buf)[j]);
        }

        close(s);
        return data;
      } 

    }

  }

 }

}
```

When I run the block externally, the model is shown running, but T=0.000 all the time. I can't even stop the model now.

Hope to get help from you.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you using the standard firmware from the LEGO Group on the EV3 or are you using a 3rd party OS? Also, both of your code samples look like they are receiving data, what is transmitting? Are you compiling and installing the c code on the EV3?

Comment: Hallo David, I am using the standard firmware from LEGO Group. And Yup I am writing the code to receive data. Basically I would want to receive all kind of data using that code, especially the measured data from other hardware. For now, I am sending a infinite sine signal from my raspberry pi and wishing that EV3 can receive the signal. The c-code is being compiled together with the simulink model onto EV3 and being executed there by the matlab function block.

Comment: I have just uploaded the warning I received during the compilation in the question above. Hope you can help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ./udp_send_receive.c:14: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit'

You are missing

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

> ./udp_send_receive.c:31: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset'
>
> ./udp_send_receive.c:66: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset'
>
> ./udp_send_receive.c:76: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strlen'

You are missing

```
#include <string.h>
```

> ./udp_send_receive.c:44: warning: passing argument 5 of 'recvfrom' from incompatible pointer type

Not exactly sure how to fix this one. Defining `__USE_GNU` may help. See `sys/socket.h`.

> ./udp_send_receive.c:70: warning: passing argument 1 of 'inet_aton' makes pointer from integer without a cast
>
> ./udp_send_receive.c:76: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Need to add `*` to parameter declarations. `char` is a single character. `char *` is a string.

```
void udp_send(char *data, char *SERVER, int PORT)
```

Comment: Thanks David! I corrected all the errors and warning in the c-code. The corrected codes are updated in the question. However, the model is still running with always T=0.0000 and stucks there. I am wondering if those headers I included are existing in EV3. Is there any way to check it?

Comment: You are never allocating any memory for `buf`. I image that the program is getting a segfualt when you try to use `buf`. In your original post, you were using `buf[BUFLEN];`, which allocates memory on the stack and is most likely what you want to do here.

Comment: Thanks David. I had corrected it and tried to run the c-code little by little. And when I comment the `recvfrom()` function like what I just updated in my question, the model is running smoothly, but of course no data received, and the data is returned -1 all the time. So firstly, I thought it should return 0 as value if no data received, since I declared `double data = 0;`? Also I can't figure out why the `recvfrom` function is not working.

Comment: I don't have access to simulink, so I don't know how data is actually returned there and why it would be -1. The `recvfrom()` function blocks until it receives data. Are you actually sending it data? Also, you currently have `return data` before `close(s)` so the socket is not being properly closed.

Comment: I see. I didn't send any data to it yet. But what I want to do is that, if no data being received in a timeout period, the data will return 0. Is there any way to achieve that? Also, when the are errors in creating or binding the socket, the data will also return 0. (But I am not quite sure if the way I wrote is correct. Basically I want to exit the function and return the output data as 0). The function is being called in infinite loops until i stop the model. It will be great if I get the data as 0 instead of waiting to receive the data, so that other components in the model can run as well.

Comment: If you are running this in a loop, I would make a separate function to bind the socket (you will need to make the socket a global variable). Then just do the receive in the loop and have another separate function to close the socket when you are done. You can use `fcntl` to make `recvfrom` non-blocking. See the `recvfrom` man page.

Comment: Thank you very much, David! I am almost there! However is there any way where I can send/receive double type directly instead of convert double to char* to send it and then convert from char* to double again after receiving it?

Comment: Yes and no. The data type will still be `char *`, but instead of converting it to a string, you can send it as binary data. A `double` is a 64-bit floating point number. So, for example, in the send function you might have `buf[sizeof(double)];` And then later, instead of the `sprintf`, you would have `*(uint64_t *)buf = htobe64((uint64_t)data);` and `size_t n = sizeof(double);`. The receive function would be similar. `data = (double)be64toh(*(uint64_t *)buf);`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't state the question clearly. What I would want to send and receive should be a vector or matrix of double values, instead of just one value each time. Is there any trick to deal with it?

Comment: Sure, you can use an array of floats the same way. So the code in my previous comment would change to `buf[sizeof(double) * N_DATA];`, `((uint64_t *)buf)[i] = htobe64((uint64_t)data[i]);`, `size_t n = sizeof(double) * N_DATA;`, `data[i] = (double)be64toh(((uint64_t *)buf)[i]);` where `N_DATA` is defined as the number of values you are sending and `i` is in a `for (i = 0; i < N_DATA; i++)` loop.

Comment: Is it char `buf[sizeof(double) * N_DATA];`? `sendto(s, buf, n , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)` returns error when I try to send the data. The modified code is again updated in the question.

Comment: I was thinking `N_DATA` would be a constant, but actually, it would be better to pass it as a parameter along with `data`, in which case I would make it lower case.

Comment: Thanks David. The sending part is doing fine after I change `N_DATA` into `n-data`. However the `recvfrom()` is returning error when I send the array to it. The receiver won't be able to know the size of the receiving array, so I put a constant on it as its max size. Why is it returning error?

Comment: I found out where the error is. It is not due to `recvfrom()` but `int n_data = sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]);` where the n_data will be used in the loop as `for (j = 0; i < N_DATA; j++)` , and as a result, `data[j] = (double)be64toh(((uint64_t *)buf)[j]);` is out of the index. But how can I find out the number of data being received?

Comment: You can either use a constant and send the same amount of data each time (some values will just be 0 if there is not an actual value). Or you can send the size as the first byte of data, then read one byte to get the size and then read the rest of the data.

Comment: Ok thanks. I get the idea now. There is one very strange thing about the sender. It was sending the correct data to correct address previously when the argument was double data (of course only scalar data could be sent). However after I change it into double * data(with n_data and loop) and try to send a scalar data, it returns error at inet_aton(), which it fails to change the ip_add to the address structure. And if I send a vector data, no error is returned, but it is the wrong address. How could this happen? Changing the type of the data argument should have nothing to do with IP-address.

Comment: You could be accidentally writing past the end of an array and writing over the ip address data structures.

Comment: Yup you are right. The matlab vector structure and the array structure in c are different. Now it is solved. However, how can I pass a scalar parameter to the c-function, which expects an array argument? I tried to pass a scalar data to the c-function that expects `double * data`, and the data is not sent to the assigned IP-address(although no error is returned). Of course I can create 2 similar c-functions, one for scalar and one for vector, but it is wasting and doesn't look neat.

Comment: You can just use an array with length of one for the scalar value or you can pass by reference (`&data`), which is essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thanks David. I created the blocks successfully with your help. However I realised that the transfer rate is decreasing by time. The longer I run the model, the slower it can transfer the data, Is it normal? Is there any suggestion to improve this?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what might be causing the slow down.